# How to implement building a universal cococs2d application?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am building an iphone application for iphone and ipad. I have texture packer .plists that contain my images. I have a normal version, an -hd version, an ipad version, and an ipadhd version.

For example, if I am currently building my menu, do I set all of them up by doing the following?

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"x_buttons.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"x_buttons-hd.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"s_buttons-ipad.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"s_buttons-ipadhd.plist"];
```

When I create a button, how does xcode 'know' which plist to use depending on the device? (iphone5, iphone4, retina, ipad etc etc)

Thank you for your help on making a universal application

Comment: If you do that, then you would be loading four sprite sheets when you only need one of them.

Comment: just follow this URL http://www.raywenderlich.com/48180/cocos2d-x-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

Answer (score 2):

John

You only need to write `[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"x_buttons.plist"];`.

In `AppDelegate.m`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` methond,
Change the following lines.

```
CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];  
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"`
```

This will help Xcode find your resource file by their suffix for iPad, iPad Retina, or iPhone Retina buildings.

Check this tutorial,
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32049/texture-packer-tutorial-how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d.

Comment: Both addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"x_buttons.plist"]; and addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"s_buttons.plist"];?

Comment: My iPad version is addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"s_buttons-ipad.plist"]; and my ipad version hd is addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"s_buttons-ipadhd.plist"];